# Failed Pig Script returns exit 0 while batch processing

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-tez

Pig script(Tez enabled) embedded in a shell wrapper returns **exit code 0** or **gracefully exits** even if it throws an error.

In case of a batch process, the task is supposed to error out and stop the process. But in this case all the downstream tasks will be executed.

Reading the Pig Jira, it is said that its fixed in **0.8.1**, but i am using **0.14** and still having the issue.
Have anyone faced such an issue?

Comment: what is the erro..can you post the stack

Comment: In case of any error, script will return exit 0.... Error is not the problem here.. But the script should return a failure in case of any error....